# Parse specific date time format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, datejs

I have a date in the following format:

`2012-12-09T02:08:34.6225152Z`

I'm using the [datejs javascript library](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) and would like the parse the above date, but I can't seem to figure out the proper format string.  I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
Date.parse('2012-12-09T02:08:34.6225152Z', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ');
```

If it's easier, I'm also open to parsing the string in native javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by changing the format of the string as it was sent to Javascript.  Instead of `2012-12-09T02:08:34.6225152Z` I changed the JSON serializer to output `1363607010099` by using the following code:

```
var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer(new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
});
```

I then changed my javascript to parse the date using this function that I found:

```
String.prototype.toDate = function () {
    "use strict";
    var match = /\/Date\((\d{13})\)\//.exec(this);
    return match === null ? null : new Date(parseInt(match[1], 10));
};
```

Finally, I output the date using this bit of code (taking advantage of the DateJS library):

```
myTime.toDate().toString('h:mm:ss tt dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

And it works.  This seems a bit hackish, so I'm more than open to consider alternatives.

Comment: Constructive suggestion: Its a bit ugly to extend the string-object with the toDate function, because not all strings can be converted to a date. Why should that function be available to all possible strings, while you only need it for one specific string only? "some".toDate() makes no sense, while ""today".toDate() or "2013-1-1".toDate() will make sense but returns null. -- just supporting :)

Comment: Good point.  I'm not suggesting that my solution is a good one, but I saw that the question was still open and wanted to close it with an accepted answer which was the way I ended up solving it.  If you have a better alternative to solve the original question, then please post your answer.  =)

Answer (score 1):

DateJS doesn't seems to support milliseconds parsing.
There's the `u` FormatSpecifier on the DateJS extras that could work (haven't tested it).

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.  The DateJs extras stuff is only for output formatting (i.e. toString()), not parsing.